# How to find the postion of certain string in the list using abstract function

Tags: python

I am trying to find the position of certain string `s` in the list, but ONLY using the abstract function (ie. filter, map...).

```
find_all([], "") => []
find_all(["a","v","c","w","v"], "v") => [1,4]
```

I have tried the filter, but I don't know how to add the position in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` with list comprehension:

```
def find_all(l, k):
    return [i for i,j in enumerate(l) if j == k]
```

Test:

```
find_all(["a","v","c","w","v"], "v")
find_all([], "")
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

`[item[0] for item in list(filter(lambda x : x[1] == 'v',enumerate(x)))]`

Output:

`[1, 4]`